# "No package found with specified pattern" while build and deploying .net core API from visual studio team services to Azure using Continuous Delivery

Tags: azure

[screen shot of the argument of publish task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HkNw.png)

[screen shot of the publish to path in artifact](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTX4l.png)

and plz dont give me reference of this link [Visual Studio Team Services Release/Deploy fails - "No package found with specified pattern"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40267656/visual-studio-team-services-release-deploy-fails-no-package-found-with-specif) because it didnt work for me..!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default .NET Core publish build task looks for web.config or wwwroot to identify a target for a web app. 
To fix this:

1. uncheck the "Publish Web Projects" checkbox
2. In the “Projects” edit box enter `*/*.csproj`

This will let the build publish the right artifacts in the drop folder for the release run to pick them up.

Comment: Above steps works..!! but I already implemented before you posted.. anyway thanx for the answer..!!